# C++ Pixels set through SetPixel are disappearing when resizing the console or moving it out of the screen

Tags: c++, windows, console, console-application, pixel

So I am currently using the SetPixel function to recolor some pixels on the screen. But when I resize the console or move the console out of the screen, the pixels which went out of the screen are black again.

How can I prevent them from getting black?

regards, TPRammus

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();    // Get a console handle

int main()
{
    HDC consoleDC = GetDC(consoleWindow);        // Get a handle to device context

    SetPixel(consoleDC, 20, 20, RGB(255, 255, 255));

    ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, consoleDC);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What library is `SetPixel` from?

Comment: Assuming this is the Win32 function,  you need to draw the pixels whenever you get a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson It is declared in the wingdi.h.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Could you give me an example on how to retrieve this WM_PAINT message?

Comment: You need to read a book on WIn32 programming - that's far too broad a topic to discuss here, but basically you need a message loop and a window procedure..

Comment: _you need a message loop and a window procedure_ ... for that you have to create your own window using [CreateWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) function. You can't just handle WM_PAINT for the console window because the console window runs in a different process ("cmd.exe") where you don't have access to.

Comment: @zett42 The console does not live in cmd.exe! It lives in csrss.exe or conhost.exe depending on the Windows version.

Comment: @Anders Why does `::GetWindowThreadProcessId( ::GetConsoleWindow(), &pid )` return the PID of "cmd.exe" then?

Comment: @zett42 Implementation details? It probably returns the PID of the first process of that console. cmd.exe is a normal console application, anyone could clone it without any special knowledge. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071231-00/?p=23983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console window is not your window, you should not be drawing on it directly!

You are allowed to use [`FillConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682662(v=vs.85).aspx) and `FillConsoleOutputCharacter` to create colored "graphics" with boxes and lines and play with the screen buffers but that is about it.

If you need pixel precision then you need to create your own window with [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) and [draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162759(v=vs.85).aspx) in `WM_PAINT`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you can do is to create an infinite loop, then inside infinite loop, the set pixel is being called here.

Kindly look at the sample code (based on what you have given):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();    // Get a console handle

int main()
{
    HDC consoleDC = GetDC(consoleWindow);        // Get a handle to device context

    while(true){
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 20, 20, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 20, 21, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 20, 22, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 20, 23, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 21, 20, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 21, 21, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 21, 22, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 21, 23, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 22, 20, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 22, 21, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 22, 22, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 22, 23, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 23, 20, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 23, 21, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 23, 22, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetPixel(consoleDC, 23, 23, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    }

    ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, consoleDC);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Not so perfect solution, as when you scroll down the console, the pixel is being replicated and looks like a trailing dot, but it gives you the idea on how to get things done. :)